# Modernizr.load/Yepnope putting conditional script first instead of last

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr, yepnope

I have an issue with yepnope that is driving me crazy, and I spent a good amount of time searching for the answer with no luck.

First, I am using device.js to detect screen size, it will throw an desktop class in the  tag if it detects a desktop.  On the desktop I want another script to be loaded which will then give functions to a certain class (on mobile devices, the script will not load and the certain classes will remain static.)

However, when yupnope executes, it throws my script on TOP of all the other scripts in my head tag and will not execute and run.  I know the script works because I manually put it in on the bottom of my other scripts.  My question is how can I make yepnope load the script last instead of putting it on the very top of the other scripts?  I have a nagging feeling that this is where a callback comes in but I am still trying to get ahold of javascript!

this is my yepnope code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('.desktop').length !=0) {
     yepnope({
    load: "js/jquery.malihu.PageScroll2id.js",
     });
   };
});
```

This is my html:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/global.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/device.js"></script>
<script src="js/fixedonlater.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

The yepnope condition is in the file scripts.js which executes last but still puts the jquery.malihu.PageScroll2id.js script that is called on top which is wrong order then as shown in this code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.malihu.PageScroll2id.js"></script> //script on top = BAD!!
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/global.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/device.js"></script>
<script src="js/fixedonlater.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle? Javascript loads in a blocking manner, so all of the scripts should have run by the time `scripts.js` runs, therefore making the order insignificant